# Error sorting object array in typescript, no correct order(with .slice() work)

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

I have a object array with this structure:

```js
let j=[
         {
            id: "924f8812-8520-41ac-b78b-8b8ea69dc169", 
            FechaHoraConexion: "2020-11-19 13:48:15",
            FechaHoraDesconexion: "2020-12-20 13:48:59"
          },
          {
            id: "e9f9d414-eba6-4af9-8a0f-4e2c9d2e4643", 
            FechaHoraConexion: "2020-11-19 13:50:27",
            FechaHoraDesconexion: "2020-11-19 13:48:15"
          },
          {
            id: "dbdbccf3-a820-49e0-93e6-fc392120cdb2",
            FechaHoraConexion: "2020-11-19 19:50:27",
            FechaHoraDesconexion: "2020-11-20 14:17:32"
           }
        ]
        let ascend=j.slice();
        let auxascend=ascend.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.FechaHoraConexion > b.FechaHoraConexion) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.FechaHoraConexion < b.FechaHoraConexion) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  let ascend2=j.slice();
  let auxascend2=ascend2.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.FechaHoraDesconexion > b.FechaHoraDesconexion) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.FechaHoraDesconexion < b.FechaHoraDesconexion) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
 //THE RESULT IS THE SAME ARRAY WITH THE SAME ORDER BUT THE ASCEND ARRAY ORDER IS INCORRECT       
 console.log(auxascend,auxascend2)
```

The acend2 array is correct but for any reason the ascend array is equal to ascend2 array. what is the reason?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `sort` sorts in place and you assign the same object reference, hence the same result.

Comment: I Don't need the same array, i need two arrays. The first one order by FechaConexion and the second order by FechaHoraDesconexion.

Comment: take a copy with `independent_array = [...array]`

Comment: I updated the post with your solution but the problem is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a copy of the array and sort the array without having the same object reference.

```js
const
    sortBy = key => (a, b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]),
    array = [{ id: "924f8812-8520-41ac-b78b-8b8ea69dc169", FechaHoraConexion: "2020-11-19 13:48:15", FechaHoraDesconexion: "2020-12-20 13:48:59" }, { id: "e9f9d414-eba6-4af9-8a0f-4e2c9d2e4643", FechaHoraConexion: "2020-11-19 13:50:27", FechaHoraDesconexion: "2020-11-19 13:48:15" }, { id: "dbdbccf3-a820-49e0-93e6-fc392120cdb2", FechaHoraConexion: "2020-11-19 19:50:27", FechaHoraDesconexion: "2020-11-20 14:17:32" }]
    auxascend = [...array].sort(sortBy('FechaHoraConexion'));
    auxascend2 = [...array].sort(sortBy('FechaHoraDesconexion'));
     
console.log(auxascend);
console.log(auxascend2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```